# Why can I not extend 'any' in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I want to make a placeholder interface for classes that use an external library. So I made:

```
export interface IDatabaseModel extends any
{
}
```

I'd rather do this and add methods later (e.g. findAll()) than mark all my classes as 'any' and have to manually search and replace 'any' in hundreds of specific places with 'IDatabaseModel' later.

But the compiler complains it cannot find 'any'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're a little confused about how interfaces work; if you use the code you have above, you'd still have to go through and replace `any` with `IDatabaseModel` in order for it to be applied.

Comment: Yeah, but I can do it as I develop the app now easily. And the add the exact methods later and remove the any to make the typings robust. But if I wait 3 months till we have 1000 files and try to find the right 'any's to replace with IDatabaseModel it'll be impractical

Comment: You can write as this, but IDatabaseModel does not work like `any`:

    type Any = any;
        
    export interface IDatabaseModel extends Any
    {
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `any` type is a way to opt-out of type checking and so it doesn't make sense to use it in an environment where type checking is done.

You could instead add your methods to the interface as you use them:

```
export interface IDatabaseModel
{
    findAll(): any;
}
```

Edit: See [Paleo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37328147/188246) for using a type alias in the meantime.

Comment: This looks bearable. But there's no other way?

Answer (score 25):

## With an alias for `any`

> I want to make a placeholder interface

Use an alias:

```
type IDatabaseModel = any;
```

## Or with an index signature [Edit from August, 2017]

[Since TypeScript 2.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/02/22/announcing-typescript-2-2/), the property access syntax `obj.propName` is allowed with an index signature:

```
interface AnyProperties {
    [prop: string]: any
}

type MyType = AnyProperties & {
    findAll(): string[]
}

let a: MyType
a.findAll() // OK, with autocomplete
a.abc = 12 // OK, but no autocomplete
```

Comment: That is groovy. Thanks!

Comment: This does almost exactly what I want to do -- that is, refer to a type that I'll flesh out later.  The only problem is that it's all or nothing.  If I use `type MyThing = any;` I can refer to `MyThing` anywhere without errors, but I don't get Intellisense help.  If I use `interface MyThing{}` I can add properties / methods but referring to anything I haven't added yet shows up as an error. Is there a "best of both worlds" that doesn't emit an error (like an `any`) but auto-completes whatever properties I've had time to describe?

Comment: @Coderer In 2016 it wasn't possible. Now it is. I just edited. :)

Comment: That's awesome!  Perfect fit for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

**2020 TLDR:**

instead of `extends any` try `extends Record<string, any>`.

**Long version:**

In certain cases `extends any` still works in TypeScript. However, in TypeScript 3.9, [it is interpreted in a more conservative way](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38238).

@Paleo creates `AnyProperties` interface in his answer. That can now be rewritten with [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) as `extends Record<string, any>`.

Answer (score 1):

"any" is a type and, unlike other basic types, doesn't appear to have an interface. Given it is a wildcard of sorts, I can't imagine what an interface to "any" could consist of.

Comment: One example: to make known to TypeScript that the user has added a function to the "Object" prototype. This way, typing `("something" as any).MyCustomFunction()` would show the info for `MyCustomFunction()` as expected.